# Where should I put methods to get a groups users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a group controller that manages groups, each group can have many users.

I want to retrieve the users using JSON but where should I put the logic and in what controller?

It's more a matter of what feels good, any suggestions?

Should I use something like `/groups/1/users` or
`/users/group/1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/groups/1/users` is the Rails way to go, especially if you use nested resources (the logic for users goes into `UsersController` naturally).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two approaches to the problem. The RESTFUL one: `/groups/1/users`, and the  other would be passing params to the `users` resource via GET: `/users?group=1`